# fissure detecting open cv

Tags: python, opencv

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf5X3.png)

I have applied thresholding on the above image. And now I want to do a program that detects the [fissure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xld6N.png). Can anybody suggest me how can I do it?

I have tried creating an algorithm that walks through the image pixels but It is not good enough
{

```
cott=15 
imm=(image[11])[1]       
tope=4
#col=75
camino=[]
total=[]

for col in range(130):
   for fil in range(149):
    ind=0 
    k=col
    cont=0
    dif=abs(int(imm[fil,k,2])-int(imm[fil+1,k,2]))
    h=fil
    diag=0
    while ind==0:    

        if dif>cott:

            k=k+1
            vec=[abs(int(imm[h,k,2])-int(imm[h+1,k,2])),abs(int(imm[h-1,k,2])-int(imm[h,k,2]))]
            dif=max(vec)
            j=vec.index(dif)

            if j==1:

                h=h-1
                cont=0
                diag=diag+1
            else:
                cont=cont+1

            if cont==tope or h<=0:
                ind=1
        else:
            ind=1        

    if cont==8:
        camino.append(0)    
    else:
         camino.append([k-col,diag]) 

total.append(max(camino))    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you show some research you've done on this topic?  See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also; post the picture, not the link.  If a link breaks, the question is less useful to future researchers/users.

Comment: Yes, I have uploaded it. I have recently started learning Python so I'm a bit noob sorry. The code I upload isn't good enough

Comment: Comment your code; it is helpful to you, and to anyone trying to read the code.  If  you modified it from some other source, let us know where it came from.  Again, make the images inline, rather than links if you can.  Also, some background on the application and particular problem can help.

Comment: I think It is not available for me to change images to inline because I have low reputation

Comment: It looks like a solar cell; have you done any research on algorithms for this?  A quick search turns up: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1687-5281-2014-15 ; I'm sure there are other people doing similar work, or programs that already do this.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize so I'm going to read what you shared with me

Comment: That is from 2014, I'm sure there are plenty of folks working on this.   Post an answer, or list of references you have found - you *are* allowed to answer your own question!

Comment: Please always post your input image separately, so that others can test with it. Have you tried using morphology to clean it up your threshold image? Have you tried inverting the threshold image and use contours sorting on area of perimeter to isolate your fissure?